# When Installing Apache Web Server

Tags: apache-2.2, web, localhost

And you go to http://localhost, are you supposed to see a message that says "It works!"

If not, how do you fix this?
Operating system: Windows 7
Apache Web Server:Win32 Binary including OpenSSL 0.9.8r (MSI Installer): httpd-2.2.19-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8r.msi

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Testing - To check and see if Apache 2 is serving. Open your browser and head to: http://127.0.0.1/ or http://localhost/

If it shows the "It works!" you have your server software installed and running.

Now it's time to make Apache point to your files:

Using Notepad open C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/conf/httpd.conf (in the start-menu there should also be a "Apache HTTP Server 2.2 > Configure Apache Server > Edit the Apache httpd.conf Configuration File" shortcut) and search for DocumentRoot. 
Change it from something like DocumentRoot "C:/Program Files/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/htdocs" to the location where your HTML files and site are located. In my case: DocumentRoot "C:/public_html"

Then scroll down about one page and change:  to point to the same location you set DocumentRoot to in the last step.

Restart apache to make the changes take effect

Comment: Of course! If this answer helped you make sure to accept my answer with the checkmark. Thanks!